# How do I check which error occurred in getUserMedia()?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, getusermedia

I'm trying to check if a user has a camera.

The MediaDevices.getUserMedia() documentation says that there are 2 possible errors: **SecurityError** and **NotFoundError**

Is there a way to detect which one of the two occurred, and do separate things for each one?

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
   video: true
})
.then(function() {
   //do something
})
.catch(function(error) {
   //if error = security error, do something
   //if error = camera not found, do something else
});
```

**EDIT**

Probably not the best way but it works for me:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true
          })
          .then(function() {
            //do stuff
           })
          .catch(function(error) {
            if(error.message.includes("Requested device not found")) //do stuff
            else if(error.message.includes("Permission denied")) //do other stuff
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not true way but it can works.

```
if(error.includes("something from security error message"){
 //do something about security
} else if(error.includes("something from camera error message"){
 //do something about camera
}
```

*Errors can be a different types (object, string). First we should look our error.*

Comment: I found out that ```error``` is an object, not a string. Changing ```error.includes``` with ```error.message.includes``` works. Be careful there are some missing parentheses, and one opening bracket too much on the else if.